# How to fix ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when a activity is reloaded in Android?

Tags: java, android, loops, android-activity, onclicklistener

I have created programmatically, 5 radio groups with 4 radio buttons each. I set `OnClickListener` on the reset button that i have created too. I want when someone clicks the button, to restart my activity. How is it even possible? When the app first time starts, it works fine but when i press the button to reload the activity, the emulator crashes. If i comment the lines where i create the radio groups and the radio buttons and i press the button, the activity is reloading fine otherwise i have this error: `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4`. How can reload the activity without issues?
Here is my code:

```
    answerGroup = new RadioGroup[5];
    answer = new RadioButton[4];
    int i = 0;
    for (Question qn : questions) {
        answerGroup[i] = new RadioGroup(this);
        answerGroup[i].setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
        int j = 0;
        for (Answer an : answers) {
            if (qn.getID() == an.getQuestion_id_answer()) {
                answer[j] = new RadioButton(this);
                answer[j].setText(an.getAnswer());
                answerGroup[i].addView(answer[j]);
                j++;
            }
        }
        linearLayout.addView(answerGroup[i]);
        i++;
    }

    restartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: please provide all logcat

Comment: what does it shows in the logcat

Comment: Yes, you are right. Here is my [entire logcat](http://www.gogo.ro/23.png)

Comment: Maybe the `questions` array is bigger then the `answerGroup` array. You're changing `i` on each iteration through the `questions` array but you're using it to access elements from the `answerGroup` array. The same goes for the `answer` array.

Comment: What is the size of your questions list? looks like it is more than 4. If it is more than 4 then it will assign j=4,which gives a arrayindexoutofboundsexception.

Comment: Ok, but what do i have to do, to fix this? And why it isn't crashing in the first place, when the activity is first time created and it crashes when the activity is recreated?

Comment: @ParagKadam: `answerGroup = new RadioGroup[5];` which represents the questions and `answer = new RadioButton[4];` What is to do?

Comment: You can use `List`s or add some checks to the iterations and `break` the loop when `i > answerGroup.length` or `j > answer.length`.  You can even set the size of the arrays beased on the other arrays `answerGroup = new RadioGroup[questions.length]`, this all depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Titus: Can you please write me some code? I don't understand you entirely. When first time the app starts it works fine, the problem is when i try to reload the activity. If i do some changes, it might not work when it starts. There are now 5 questions but normally there will be at least 25.  So, it can be like this `answerGroup = new RadioGroup[25];` while the answers will always remain like that: `answer = new RadioButton[4];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The activity is probably trying to reference to old view elements (from before the Activity restart). Try to add your view components:

- RadioGroup
- RadioButton

As class variables. Can you try that and tell me what it is doing? I will update this answer according to the input you give me.

**EDIT:**

I assume that you are using a `ArrayList<Question>` and `ArrayList<Answer>` as the `questions` and `answers` variable.

```
      for (Question qn : questions) {
            RadioGroup answerGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
            answerGroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
            for (Answer an : qn.getAnswers()) {
                if (qn.getID() == an.getQuestion_id_answer()) {
                    RadioButton answer = new RadioButton(this);
                    answer.setText(an.getAnswer());
                    answerGroup.addView(answer);
                }
            }
            linearLayout.addView(answerGroup);
        }
```

Maybe you should add a getter method to your question called: `getAnswers();` and a variable to your `Question` model called `List<Answer> answers`. Ofcourse, these answers need to be set before you try to do anything with them.

Comment: Ok, i wiil try but how can i add my view components? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Isn't there a possibility to create these views in your layout files? If you restart the activity, the lifecycle of your view elements are handled by the Android framework. There is another possibility: where does your `questions` variable come from? Is it cleared upon activity restart?

Comment: Yes i am using: `List<Question> questions = db.getAllQuestions();` and `List<Answer> answers = db.getAllAnswers();` but if do as you say, i get this error: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5`

Comment: But you should add a pre-step. Why are you getting all of the answers in the DB? Why aren't you only adding the answers relevant to the question?

Comment: That you are still getting ArrayOutOfBoundsException still indicates that you are using arrays instead of lists. Do you have the full code to share somewhere?

Comment: Ok, I miss some things in your code. First, you are still using arrays for the radiogroups and radiobuttons. I only see code inside your class and not within any method? Can you share the code of your full Activity in a https://gist.github.com/? Because you left some crucial details out I suspect.

Comment: I never user Github, but i am going to. I am really at the beginning. But for the moment, please take a closer look at [my entire MainActivity](http://www.gogo.ro/24.txt). There you can see all my code.

Comment: I can't see any changes. Can you please refresh [this](http://gogo.ro/24.txt) It's the entire MainActivity code.

Comment: @AlexM. My quess will be that you have more then 4 answers per questions, that could happen if you have duplicate entries in your database. You're always adding entries in the database when the `Activity` starts, which means that when the activity restarts, it will add another 4 answers for each question which will make it 8 answers per question.

Comment: Yes, that a good point. Never thought about this. How can i fix this?

Comment: @AlexM. you can make a primary key in the answers table and set its value to someting unique (maybe a combination of the question's id and the answer's number), this will prevent duplicates.

Comment: Or you can count the number of answers that belong to a question (because you do save the question id in the answer). And if there are already 4 answers, don't add them to the database.

Comment: Yes i do save the question id in the answer. But how do you think i can do that? I don't know how. Can you please write me some lines according to my code?

Comment: Ok, I have another question for you. Why don't you try it without the database first. Just make the answers and questions each time the activity starts. If that works, try using the database. Try to start simple. That is mostly the way to go within application development - and software engineering - as a whole.

Comment: Thanks, i will try do that. But if i want to count the number of answers that belong to a question and if there are already 4 answers, to restrict them from adding to the database, how can i do?

Comment: Count the number of answers that belong to a question id. If that number is == 4, then proceed without adding. If this isn't the case, add them to your db.

Comment: I will try both ideas and i will came back with an answer. Dankjewel ;)

Comment: Well ok. Graag gedaan :).

Comment: Well, i tried exactly as you said, first time with no database and i want to say, it worked fine. After that i put back the database and tried to do some changes. I have added a value that is unique, and then check the database value if already exists or not during insert. With other words, if  you find something there don't insert data otherwise insert. In the end this is the result [MainActivity](http://www.gogo.ro/25.txt) and [DBHandler](http://www.gogo.ro/26.txt). Same error. I don't know what to do anymore. Do you have any new idea?

Comment: I have combined all your answers, changing the database, `ArrayLists` and now it's finally working. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You must debug your code, probably **not all** your questions have 4 answers.

If one of your questions have more than 4 answers (eg: 5), and you try to loop through them you get the **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** because `j>=4`.

---

As a solution: try to use a `List` for your `RadioButtons`:

```
List<RadioButton> answer = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
```

And for each iteration add a new `RadioButton`:

```
answer.add(new RadioGroup(this));
```

---

PS: Also i suggest you to use [recreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate%28%29) method to reload/recreate your activity.

Comment: All my questions have for sure 4 answers. I'm extracting those questions and answers from the database. If there were more than 4 answers per question, for sure i had this issue in the first place. I tried to do this and the emulator crashed at start. It's true, for the simplicity of this example are only 5 questions with 4 answers but at a moment, in stead of 5 questions, will be at least 25 but the number of answers will remain the same, 4.
Can you please write me some lines according to my example? I do not understand you entirely. The `recreate()` method do i use also in the `onClick`? Ty